# How can I use standard built'in windows8.1's voice engines (or speech engines) on my Windows 7?

Tags: winapi, windows-7, windows-8.1, speech

How can I use standard built'in windows8.1's voice engines (speech engines) on my Windows 7?
Should I install any SDKs or manually move some files (dll files, etc) to windows 7 and use them directly?

Comment: How would you use any other Windows 8.1 built-in feature on Windows 7? You do this the same way: upgrade to Windows 8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  There's lots of implicit state that isn't encapsulated in DLL files.

(I'm assuming you're talking about TTS engines, not speech recognition engines.  The SR engines haven't been updated from Windows 7 to Windows 8.1.)